# Why does webpack skip my local module?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, webpack, ionic2

I put some common code in this local module called 'client-common'. In one of the app project using this common module, I add this to package.json dependencies:

```
"client-common": "../client-common"
```

After `npm install` the module gets copied to node_modules. When I run (it's an Ionic project) `ionic serve`, it builds all fine, but at runtime in the browser I get

```
Runtime Error
Cannot find module "client-common"
```

I'm assuming this is a webpack issue? The question is why is the local module treated differently and not bundled at all?

Comment: What's in "../client-common"? Can you show more of the package.json and webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was supposed to supply an index.js in the common module. After adding an index.js duplicated from the existing index.d.ts, exporting everything, it just works now.